# Is it possible to stream video p2p (or other technology) between iOS, Android, Browser

Tags: android, ios, flash, cross-browser, cross-platform

I'm just learingn mobile web development and thinking about task:
Is there a way to make a videostream betwen iOS, Android and Browser. What architecture and technology it should use. I already read this quetion on SO [Peer-to-Peer video from iOS to Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786158/peer-to-peer-video-from-ios-to-android) but there is nothing about browsers.

If it can't be p2p and crossplatfom at the same time. I thought i shoud use Red5 server or etc. or Xmpp

So I'm asking your advice and opinion here. Any information would be valuable

Comment: I think you are talking about video calling like google hangout?

Comment: Yeah, what can u suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, You can !!!

There is new technology enforced by google is [WEBRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started)

It is stands for "web real time communication" and is an opensource project funded by google.

It is also support Android/iPhone native application.

I am working on it and got success say 60%.

Video clarity is good but audio is choppy.

You can find source code from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/checkout)

Discussion with community [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc)

You can see live demo [Here](https://apprtc.appspot.com)

**NOTE:**

It is ongoing project and has not been stable yet. Google team is working on.Currently it is working on latest Chrome,FF and opera. IE has not given support yet.

Comment: thanks for response and answer. I would be very thankful if you write some links about webrtc development for iOS and android. I found a lot of recourses about making webrtc on browsers but none for Apps. Thanks

Comment: you can write them to my email if it not allowed here. My email razoronline@mail.ru

Comment: demo for android and iphone available in webrtc source code

Answer (score 0):

Yes,the open source solution should be WEBRTC technology,please check it on official website: webrtc.org